# Hangman C++ Printing Shapes from a String Array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am coding a hangman game. I have a string array, made up of 10 different hangman shapes. Lets say my string array is called myHangmanPics:

```
std::string myHangmanPics[9];
```

Here is an example of what is contained in one index:

[Example of a text shape (pistol) which I've stored in myHangmanPics[0]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh2Yl.png)

Each index of the array  (size 10) contains a different hangman shape, such as the one above. I have used a random number generator to randomly select an index (from 0-9) for the hangman shapes array, and thus a random hangman shape.

---

OK, now the problem.

I want to print out one line of the hangman shape (in succession) from the chosen index  for every wrong user guess. The 1st guess will print the first line, which is only underscores as seen in the picture above. The 2nd wrong guess will print the 2nd line, and so on until the whole shape has been printed. Here is an example of what I mean:

[Desired output after 1-5 wrong guesses.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuzBk.png)

I've been successful in figuring out how to register the wrong guesses, but I am having difficulties printing out one line at a time. The shapes do have a newline character '\n' at the end of each line of the shape, as you can see in the first picture.

Given this info, what would be the simplest way to implement this? Highly appreciates.

Comment: Let's do a thought experiment. Try to empty your mind of everything you know about your code in question. Pretend that you are some stranger, halfway across the world, who hasn't seen a line of your code. You are this stranger, you clicked on this question, and you just read it. Now, do you have any idea what this question is all about?

Comment: Fair enough, I will add some more detail about my code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Merge` function here combines two strings as 2D images, treating spaces as transparent.  The first character in both strings will be at the top-left position in the result.  The example in `main` demonstrates how to use linefeed and space padding to position a string within the merged result.

**Edited to include a version of the same code which doesn't use auto**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// NextLine returns the substring in s starting at pos and ending
// in a newline character (not included).
// pos is set to the beginning of the next line, or the
// length of the string if the end is reached.
std::string NextLine(const std::string &s, std::size_t &pos) {
    if(pos >= s.length()) { return {}; }
    const auto start = pos;
    const auto nlpos = s.find('\n', start);
    if(nlpos == std::string::npos) {
        pos = s.length();
        return s.substr(start); 
    } else {
        pos = nlpos + 1;
        return s.substr(start, nlpos - start);
    }
}

// Merge creates a compisition of two strings
// The space character is treated as transparent
// If two non-transparent characters occupy the same
// position, the character from string b is used.
std::string Merge(std::string a, std::string b) {
    std::size_t pos_a=0, pos_b=0;
    std::string result;
    while(pos_a < a.length() || pos_b < b.length()) {
        if(!result.empty()) { result += '\n'; }
        auto line_a = NextLine(a, pos_a);
        auto line_b = NextLine(b, pos_b);
        auto len = line_a.length();
        if(len > line_b.length()) {
            line_b += std::string(len - line_b.length(), ' ');
        }
        else if(len < line_b.length()) {
            len = line_b.length();
            line_a += std::string(len - line_a.length(), ' ');
        }
        for(std::size_t i=0; i<len; ++i) {
            result += line_b[i] == ' ' ? line_a[i] : line_b[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::string parts[] = {
        " O ",
        "\n | ",
        "\\ /",
        "\n\n/ \\"
    };
    std::string man;
    bool first = true;
    for(auto p : parts) {
        if(first) { first = false; }
        else      { std::cout << "---\n"; }
        man = Merge(man, p);
        std::cout << man << '\n';
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
 O 
---
 O 
 | 
---
\O/
 | 
---
\O/
 | 
/ \
```

Here is a version which does not use `auto`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string NextLine(const std::string &s, std::size_t &pos) {
    if(pos >= s.length()) { return {}; }
    const std::size_t start = pos;
    const std::size_t nlpos = s.find('\n', start);
    if(nlpos == std::string::npos) {
        pos = s.length();
        return s.substr(start); 
    } else {
        pos = nlpos + 1;
        return s.substr(start, nlpos - start);
}   }
std::string Merge(std::string a, std::string b) {
    std::size_t pos_a=0, pos_b=0;
    std::string result;
    while(pos_a < a.length() || pos_b < b.length()) {
        if(!result.empty()) { result += '\n'; }
        std::string line_a = NextLine(a, pos_a);
        std::string line_b = NextLine(b, pos_b);
        std::size_t len = line_a.length();
        if(len > line_b.length()) {
            line_b += std::string(len - line_b.length(), ' ');
        } else if(len < line_b.length()) {
            len = line_b.length();
            line_a += std::string(len - line_a.length(), ' ');
        }
        for(std::size_t i=0; i<len; ++i) {
            result += line_b[i] == ' ' ? line_a[i] : line_b[i];
    }   }
    return result;
}
int main() {
    std::string parts[] = {" O ", "\n | ", "\\ /", "\n\n/ \\" };
    std::string man;
    for(std::size_t i=0; i<sizeof(parts)/sizeof(parts[0]); ++i) {
        if(i) { std::cout << "---\n"; }
        man = Merge(man, parts[i]);
        std::cout << man << '\n';
}   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it looks helpful, however I am getting the following errors in my compiler when I try to compile: 'start' does not have a type, 'nlpos' does not have a type, also line_a and line_b. Is this due to my compiler?

Comment: @MadhurP `auto` was redefined in the C++11 Standard. You likely need to turn on C++11 support or get a newer compiler.

Comment: Much appreciates. The first one also worked when I added a c++11 flag into gcc